# Minimum C++ version required by MFC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I'm preparing some material about MFC and I want to specify the minimum C++ version required by it (not necessarily for every MFC version, though it would be great). Unfortunately I haven't been able to find that information. What I have so far is the MFC version per VS release [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library#Versions).

On the other hand, AFAIU, there is a minimum C++ version on each Visual Studio version (at least on recent VS). For example, in VS 2017 the minimum version is C++14 (and you can increase it to C++17 using `/std:c++17`). Does it means that the MFC for VS 2017 *requires* C++14? (I guess no).

Taking a look at many of the classes provided by MFC, my guess is that it only requires either C++98 or C++03, but I cannot find anything that confirms or rejects that theory.

Where can I find the minimum C++ version required by a given version of MFC?

Comment: Looking at the MFC source code I seriously doubt that MFC requires anything > C++03. maybe even C+98 is enough. I've never seen any modern C++ or the usage of STL in the MFC source code. But I'm not sure either.

Comment: MFC's [exception handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/exception-handling-in-mfc) strategies predate even C++98. It's pretty safe to assume that MFC is happy with *any* C++ (even before it became an ISO standard), so long as it's Microsoft's. It does use MSVC-specific extensions, though, so there may be mapping between MFC and Visual Studio versions. Though I doubt that anything newer than VC++6 is actually required.

Comment: _a minimum C++ version on each Visual Studio version_ I don't think so. I can remember that VS2012 was followed by VS2013 very soon which claimed to support (most of) C++11. Until VS2012, (I believe) MS was rather ignoring C++ standards (by policy). Instead, they rather picked out what they found useful and "lived in their own world". This has radically changed in the recent decade. (Maybe, due to the success of mobile devices and the corresponding loss of market shares concerning PCs.)

Comment: That c++ setting is for the c++ code that you write yourself, it has little to do with MFC. For any new project, you may choose the latest c++ version so you can use the latest c++ code. Or sometimes you have to choose older c++ version if particular files in your code should be backward compatible or you don't want to make changes to them. MFC is not 100% compatible with some new c++ features, so the compiler may issue warnings on some MFC code. Microsoft is actively trying to fix that, but they take their time.

Comment: I don't think it is an issue. I use MFc and C++20. But as @BarmakShemirani says, we get some code analysis warnings because of the way code is written. But that does depend upon what code analysis settings you use. Native Microsoft code analisis shows no warning. But c++ core will show issues with unscoped enums (as an example).